# Big space in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, doctype

Not sure if you can help but I have a problem with a webpage I have built.

`109.108.140.137`

In Firefox and Chrome it appears fine but in IE (8) there is a gap at the top. It's not related to any incorrect div tags but appears to be a doctype issue. I'm more of a SQL programmer than a web developer but any ideas on how I can remove that gap?

Not too good with IE coding..

Comment: Did you use a CSS reset? It is useful to start with the same base for all browsers. Try there for some common resets:  http://www.cssreset.com/

Comment: I found something about it in old notes here about a small gap at the top in IE 7 and lower. Seems like your problem. It says to save the file in ANSI instead of UTF-8.